# O(logn) runtime of a while loop?

Tags: runtime, time-complexity, big-o

I saw these two examples online and I am trying to figure out the runtime for each. I have a guess as to what both runtimes could be, but I am not positive especially the second problem.

```
    int temp=0;
    int i=0;
    while(temp < n){
        arr[i]++;
        i++;
        temp = i*i;
    }
```

I believe the runtime for this is O(log n) because the while loop runs approximately n*2 times, which makes me think that's what it is.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
while (j<n){
    i++;
    if(i==n){
        i = 0;
        j = j*2;
    }
}
```

My best guess at this is also O(logn). I don't really know how to think about this problem. I know that each subproblem (to get inside the if statement) runs n times. Therefore the runtime is about O(n*3)(I think) == O(logn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet is equivalent to:

```
int i=0;
while(i*i < n){
    arr[i]++;
    i++;
}
```

which has complexity `O(sqrt(n))` because `i*i < n` is the same as `i < sqrt(n)`.

For the second

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
while (j<n){
  i++;
  if(i==n){
    i = 0;
    j = j*2;
  }
}
```

let's observe that `j` is reset after `n` steps to `2*j`. If this happens `k` times, `j` will become `2^k`. Since the limit is `n`, we have `2^k < n` or `k < lg(n)`. In sum, there will be `lg(n)` resets of `j`, each of them involving `n` steps. Hence the complexity is `O(n lg(n))`.